# Sound PROBLEM HP Spectre x360

Tags: sound, odin

Ever since I used the elementary os hera and now EOS Odin I have had problems with the sound the microphone doesn't work at all and the speakers too. please help. I am using an HP Specter X360 laptop
Sound Intel® Smart Sound Technology. TNX

Now I use Windows 11 Pro so i cant do terminal
Speecy:

```
Audio  
    Sound Card  
        Intel Smart Sound Technology  
    Playback Device  
        Speakers (Intel Smart Sound Technology)  
    Recording Device  
        Microphone (Intel Smart Sound Technology)   

Operating System  
    Windows 11 Pro 64-bit  
CPU  
    Intel Core i7 5500U @ 2.40GHz   41 °C  
    Broadwell-U 14nm Technology  
RAM  
    8,00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 (12-15-15-34)  
Motherboard    
    Hewlett-Packard 802D (SOCKET 0)  
Graphics  
    Generic PnP Monitor (2560x1440@60Hz)  
    Intel HD Graphics 5500 (HP)  
Storage  
    476GB MTFDDAV512TBN-1AR1ZABHA (SATA (SSD))  36 °C  
Optical Drives  
    No optical disk drives detected  
Audio  
    Intel Smart Sound Technology
```

Comment: There are a few different audio chipsets that HP has used in its Spectre models. Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -c audio` and `sudo lspci`? This will hopefully contain enough device-specific information to offer a solution 

Comment: For a start try with `sudo apt install linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04` and post the output of `lspci` so that we know what audio card you really have.